# Self-induction of a simple wire/circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, inductance, ferromagnetism

I've been working as an EE intern for the past 5 months and have been trying to wrap my head around a couple concepts.

Is the principle of self-inductance due to a circuit's inherent property of being a loop of wire? Or is it that loops are simply the most efficient shape with which to sum of a bunch of magnetic field in one area—the center of the loop? which would mean that, unless a circuit's dimensions are small and it forms an efficient loop shape, a wire intrinsically has self inductance. From this latter case, is any wire's self-inductance due to eddy currents (is that how ferrite beads work in filtering out high frequencies) and is there a good explanation/simulation of this phenomenon?

[image] [image]

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Any wire in an inductor. A changing current will face an induced tension tending to decrease it.

A coil of $n$ rings maximize the induction because the area limited by any closed (immaginary) path passing inside and outside the coil will be crossed by $n$ times the current. And the magnetic field around the loop is proportional to that total current.